# How can I create a CSS3 overflow hidden unmasking spotlight effect with rotation?

Tags: html, css, overflow, masking

I want to create an effect whereby I have a static image, and that image is being unmasked by a rotating mask. I understand there is no way to do native masking in HTML5/CSS (that works in all browsers) so I'm using the mask:overflow method.

I came across this link posted by Google:
https://storage.googleapis.com/html5-demos/MaskRotateTranslate/index.html

I'm trying to achieve what's pictured in the second example. The only difference is that I don't need the inner image to animate, only it's "mask".

This example appears to have been generated via Google Web Designer, so I can't really use it's code.

I attempted to recreate it using the counter animation method (A div inside a div. The outer div acts as the 'mask'. When the outer div moves 30px to the right, the other moves -30px, creating the illusion of static content). This method worked for me until I started rotating the divs. Rotation seems to affect the x and y values of the content which kind of messes up the countering effect.

Long story short.. How can I achieve a similar effect using simple Javascript or CSS animation? Has anyone had any success with this type of animation?

Comment: Text to long, task still unclear (at least for me).

Answer (score 1):

Here is my try :

```css
.image {
  width: 400px;
  height: 300px;
  background-image: url(http://placekitten.com/800/600);
  background-size: contain;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  animation: inner 4s infinite;
}

.container {
  width: 400px;
  height: 300px;
  left: 400px;
  position: relative;
  animation: outer 4s infinite;
  border: solid red 1px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

@keyframes inner {
  from {transform:  rotate(0deg) translate(500px);} 
  to {transform:  rotate(360deg) translate(0px); } 
}

@keyframes outer {
  from {transform: translate(-500px) rotate(0deg);} 
  to {transform: translate(0px) rotate(-360deg);} 
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="image"></div>
  </div>
```